# Geometrical construction of 7th roots of unity given parabola x^2

Tags: geometric-construction, roots-of-unity

Given parabola $x^2$ on plane, how can I construct 7th roots of unity?

I was straying with my only idea, that sum of squares of real and imaginary part of roots of 1 equals 1 and belongs to $\mathbb{Q}$, but it leads me nowhere.

Also I know that group of 7th roots of unity is cyclic and isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_7$, but I think it won't be useful here.

Answer (score 5):

Start with the fact that the algebraic integers $2\cos(2k\pi/7), k\in\{1,2,3\}$ solve the equation $x^3+x^2-2x-1=0$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2472267/248217), for instance).

Begin by multiplying this equation by $x-1$, turning it into a depressed quartic:

$x^4-3x^2+x+1=0$

Now from the given parabola, $x^4=y^2$. With this $y^2$ term we will begin the process of defining a circle by "borrowing" $x^2$ from the quadratic term in $x$:

$y^2-3x^2+x+1=0$

$(x^2+y^2)-4x^2+x+1=0$

Next eliminate the $4x^2$ term in favor of $4y$, and now you can use completing the square to define the circle:

$(x^2+y^2)-4y+x+1=0$

$(x^2+x)+(y^2-4y)=-1$

$\color{blue}{(x+\frac12)^2+(y-2)^2=\frac{13}4}$

Thus, identify the point $(-\frac12,2)$ by usual means and draw a circle centered there through the point $(1,1)$ on the parabola (corresponding to the auxiliary root $x=1$). The circle will intersect the parabola at three other points corresponding to $x=2\cos(2k\pi/7), k\in\{1,2,3\}$. From there the construction of the actual seventh roots as points on the coordinate plane (now reinterpreted as the complex number plane) is straightforward.

---

This method can be used to solve any cubic equation. For example, if we start with $x^3=2$, the steps above lead to $(x-1)^2+(y-\frac12)^2=\frac54$, so you draw the circle centered at $(1,\frac12)$ and passing through the origin to get $x^3=2$ at the other intersection. Ultimately, because quartic equations may be rendered from resolvent cubics, this shows that **all  solid constructions are derivable using the parabola $y=x^2$ as the only noncircular conic section.**

Comment: Great answer! Can I just ask for a point of clarification - what exactly do you mean by a "solid construction" in your last paragraph?

Comment: "Solid construction" is a Greek term for constructions with conic sections; tge Greeks imagined that the conic sections coukd be drawn if their straightedge and compasses could be extended into the third dimension.

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you!